# uwsgi: connection refused when running from startup script

Tags: django, ubuntu, permissions, wsgi, uwsgi

I want to run a django site on amazon ec2 (ubuntu) with nginx and uwsgi. I have followed a basic setup as described [here](http://posterous.adambard.com/start-to-finish-serving-mysql-backed-django-w).

When I start uwsgi from the command line (as ubuntu user), everything works fine, the site is served up properly:

```
/home/ubuntu/uwsgi-1.3/uwsgi --home /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env/site/ --socket /tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock --chmod-socket --module mysite_wsgi --pythonpath /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env/site/mysite/production -H /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env
```

However when I want to demonize this via a startup script, uwsgi reports the following error:

```
2012/11/06 12:50:08 [error] 1773#0: *10 connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.66.145.99, server: *.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock:", host: "mysite.com"
```

(this looks like a permissions issue)

my startup script looks like this

```
# file: /etc/init/uwsgi_mysite.conf 
description "uWSGI server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /home/ubuntu/uwsgi-1.3/uwsgi --home /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env/site/ --socket /tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock --chmod-socket 777 --module mysite_wsgi --pythonpath /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env/site/mysite/production -H /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env
```

I have tried to execute the startup command as ubuntu user
`exec sudo -u ubuntu "command...`"
but to no avail.

I also tried to change permissions for the socket file by passing in

```
--chmod-socket 777
```

but no luck here either. I'm out of ideas as to how to fix this, any input is appreciated!

Comment: "I have tried to execute the startup command as ubuntu user exec sudo -u ubuntu "command..." but to no avail", humn, did you try adding --uid in your uwsgi invocation in the startup script ? Also, does it work if you manually chmod 777 the socket ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, manually changing the socket perms to 777 has no effect, and passing in a --uid neigher though... any other suggestions? :) cheers!

Comment: Well yes in that case I just do `strace -p [PID THAT SHOULD ACCESS THE SOCKET (the HTTPD)]` and read the error. But I don't understand, you say that uwsgi logs `2012/11/06 12:50:08 [error] 1773#0: *10 connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.66.145.99, server: *.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock:", host: "mysite.com"`, are you sure that it's not nginx that is logging that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the connection error was caused by the permission problems of /tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock file.

Try adding "--uid YOURNAME --gid www-data" and "--chmod-socket 666" options to your upstart script like below. And make sure YOURNAME is in www-data group (the default nginx group).

```
exec /home/ubuntu/uwsgi-1.3/uwsgi --uid YOURNAME --gid www-data --home /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env/site/ --socket /tmp/uwsgi_mysite.sock --chmod-socket 666 --module mysite_wsgi --pythonpath /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env/site/mysite/production -H /home/ubuntu/apps/mysite-env
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day.. The important part is the user should be part of the www-data group!